# Правильность постановки тире в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Это очень важно - хорошо поспать.

Возможно ли в данном случае употребление тире? Если да, возможна ли альтернатива в виде двоеточия? Чем будут отличаться варианты с тире и двоеточием? Возможна ли запятая?

Answer (score 2):

***Это очень важно — хорошо поспать.***

Ставится только тире. Это **инверсия** следующего предложения: *Хорошо поспать* (подл.) — *это важно* (сказ.).

Розенталь: § 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92
5. При наличии паузы между главными членами предложения тире ставится между **ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ, выраженным НЕОПР. ФОРМОЙ ГЛАГОЛА**, и **сказуемым, выраженным предикативным наречием на -о (категорией состояния)**:

Уступить — позорно (Тендр.); Это очень несносно — переезжать (Гонч.); Это ужасно — струсить в последний момент; Это чертовски весело — кататься на лодке [ср. без паузы: Кататься на лодке весело; Судить человека в немилости очень легко (Л. Т.)].

**Двоеточие** (наряду с тире)  допускается  в пояснительной конструкции: Здесь важно **одно** — хорошо поспать. Здесь важно **только одно**: хорошо поспать.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

Возможна также постановка двоеточия (чтобы избежать двух тире): ***Предложен и другой путь***: использование некоторых видов морских растений — водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами.

Comment: Какая инверсия... В предложении автора подлежащее "это", а не "поспать".

Comment: @Niemand А где подлежащее в приведенном примере из Розенталя: "Это очень несносно — переезжать"?

Comment: @grizzly Это не пример из Розенталя. Естественно, подлежащее "это". А "переезжать", видимо, дополнение (несносно что? - переезжать).

Comment: @Niemand Эта цитата из Гончарова приведена в качестве примера в справочнике Розенталя. В этом справочнике сказано, что в данном предложении "переезжать" — подлежащее, а "несносно" — сказуемое. Я поражаюсь, насколько Вы упорствуете каждый раз в своих ошибках. Пожалуйста, давайте свои альтернативные версии в качестве ответов, а не комментариев к правильным ответам других участников — ведь Вы только сбиваете с толку спрашивающих.

Comment: А "это" тогда что?